# Mailgun: Failed to create domain. Domain quota exceeded for the account

Tags: mailgun

I am getting an error when trying to create a new domain for another website. I am a web developer and I host many sites so I need to have a lot of domains. How can I add more domains?
Currently on the Free plan (because my sites don't exceed the limit) however it seems like I need to upgrade... I can't find any limitations at all for domains.

Does any one know what I can do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that the free plan does not allow for custom domains. Once you add a credit card, you will be given 5,000 emails for free and a 3 month trial of the flex plan. This plan allows for up to 5 domains max. If you have more than 5 domains you may want to reach out to the sales team to see about a custom plan, they are able to accomodate adding more domains. [Here is a link to the differences between plans](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/faqs.html#faq).

Once you have upgraded (or added a credit card!), you can add a domain by following [these steps](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/203637190-How-Do-I-Add-or-Delete-a-Domain-):

Inside the Mailgun Control Panel (options displayed down the left-hand side on a dark column), use the following instructions:

First, click on Sending on the left-hand side of your the Mailgun dashboard. Then click the green Add New Domain button. Enter your Domain Name and choose your additional options. The region your domain will reside: US or EU.

Next step is to create DKIM Authority - you would generally leave this checked by default. Then, decide on DKIM Length - a longer DKIM key will make spoofing your emails by malicious spammer more difficult. 1024-bit is selected by default, but 2048-bit can be used as well. Keep in mind that some DNS providers may have an issue with a 2048-bit DKIM keys, as they produce a string longer than 255 characters (exceeding the maximum character limit for a DNS entry). Once your options are set, click Add Domain to save your new domain.